# FTP Publisher for CruiseControl.Net?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Does anyone know how to use CruiseControl.Net to publish to an FTP server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a specific way to do this. You can of course always run the commandline ftp client in window from cruise control.net

One tip:

I found that stuff like this can be hard to set up and maintain in cc.net. There's a lot of trial and error involved and because you're working on a server every trial and every error can take a long time to debug. I usually have a very generic cc.net build setup that i can copy for all my projects that just gets the source from version-control and starts a nant build script. Because you can run the nant build-script on your local machine as well debugging it is far easier.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter with compiler you are using, from version 1.5 there is an FTP publisher, which is using free assembly `edtFTPnet.dll`, it automatically publishes any information.
Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

We had aa problem at work in that we need to do a lot of file operations during our builds, so i wrote a plugin to do this.

Resource wise, this is very easy to do, all the information i needed was in this link:
http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Custom+Builder+Plug-in

with the exception that i implemented iTask, not iBuilder.

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MSBuild with CC.NET then you can use the [FTP Task for MS Build](http://www.digizzle.com/Projects/FtpTask/Default.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to take the FTP task for CC.Net route you should be aware that in version 1.5 there is an issue causing all of the files to be copied to the FTP server again even if they haven't changed since the previous upload.

In spite of that I am successfully using it for two smaller sites. I've [blogged](http://www.damirscorner.com/UsingFTPTaskInCruiseControlNETForPublishingWebsites.aspx) about my experiences setting it up.